# Why is my git history showing "branches" for tags?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've been trying to maintain my git history so I can refer back to it and quickly understand it later on. I prefer to rebase my changes so that `main` is a long list of changes with only a few current branches at the "top" of the trunk which are deleted as changes get merged in.

I rebase all WIP branches onto the end of `develop` as I complete the work, tag the commit with a version and then rebase `develop` onto the end of `main`.

For some reason though (having removed all branches apart from main), my history looks like this with "branches" and inconsistent tag ordering. What have I done wrong for this not to be a single, clean line of history and can it be corrected?

```
* f786123 (HEAD -> main, tag: v1.6.7, origin/main, origin/HEAD) v1.6.7
* 87a3eaf Some commit message
* abdaed5 v1.6.4
* 96bd2fc Some commit message
| * 793ff16 (tag: v1.6.6) Some commit message
| * 5479027 Some commit message
| * ec2b811 (tag: v1.6.5) Some commit message
| * 0e5f658 Some commit message
| * 6e552df (tag: v1.6.4) v1.6.4
| * d74123b Some commit message
|/  
* d9e43cc Some commit message
* 357ada0 v1.6.3
```

Condensed output of `git log --graph --oneline --tags`

Comment: Thanks @torek, the link you shared gives a little insight in the difference between branches and subgraphs - I'll investigate this further. My confusion stems, I suppose, from the fact that given my HEAD position it would appear d74123b to 793ff16 still appear to be part of current change list when the graph would imply that they're not.

Comment: "still appear to be part of current change list" There is no such thing as a "current change list". You might benefit from finding out what Git is. This could help: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: I apologise if my nomenclature isn't perfect. What I'm saying is the changes made in d74123b to 793ff16 are reflected in files when the graph seems to imply they shouldn't be. I may be misunderstanding the graph, but it'd be great if in the process of answering my question, that too was explained a little. - Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: "What I'm saying is the changes made in d74123b to 793ff16 are reflected in files when the graph seems to imply they shouldn't be" Commits aren't "changes". They are complete immutable states of your project — snapshots. It doesn't matter what the graph history is; if the snapshot `f786123` contains those files in that state, for whatever reason (which is impossible to reconstruct now because you've messed with the graph), you can mess with the graph further all you like but _that_ snapshot will forever contain _those_ files in _that_ state.

Answer (score 1):

> What have I done wrong for this not to be a single, clean line of history

**tl;dr:** In the future, most likely your problem will be solved if you merge `develop` into `main` instead of rebasing it onto `main`.

**Details:**
The tags being left off of `main` happened because you rewrote tagged commits. Tags, like branches, are pointers to a commit except that tags are intended to be permanent, whereas branches are intended to move around and point to new commits. By rebasing the `develop` branch *after* you had already tagged some commits on `develop`, you rewrote all of those commits. When we say "rewrite" a commit in Git, what we actually mean is to create a brand new commit that is similar to the previous version of the commit. But since it is not *identical*, the commit ID will change, and the already created tag will only be pointing to the older version of the commit instead of the new one. When you display the log of your `main` branch by itself it is actually linear, but when you use the option to include tags you're also going to see the old version of the commits that those tags are still pointing to. Perhaps you expected that when you rewrite a commit, that the tags would also get rewritten, but that is not the case.

As for some commits not appearing on `main` at all, well, something did not happen as you expected, and it's not possible to know for sure what that was from your question. Fortunately, *why* those commits are gone from `main` doesn't really matter, since it's obvious what you want the final outcome to be.

Given then,

> can it be corrected?

It appears that you have two separate problems:

1. Some tags are pointing to the commits before they were rewritten.
2. About 4 commits are not on the `main` branch.

I'm going to assume you are fine rewriting your `main` branch. In this case perhaps the simplest solution is reset your `main` branch to commit `793ff16`, and then cherry-pick the top two commits on `main`, like this:

```
git switch main
git reset --hard 793ff16
git cherry-pick 87a3eaf^..f786123
```

Note you can actually do this all in one command with a fancy rebase, like this:

```
git rebase 87a3eaf^ main --onto 793ff16
```

At this point your branch will have the desired commits in the desired order, but the last tag is missing from `main`. So now, recreate the missing tag to point to the new commit, which in this case is the head commit:

```
git tag v1.6.7 -f # you need to force it since it already exists
```

**Disclaimer:** whether you can rewrite your branch and tags as described also depends on whether you already pushed any of this to a remote. If you have, you may need to coordinate with other users of the repo first.

In the future, if you like tagging the commits once they land on `develop`, consider merging `develop` into `main` instead of rebasing `develop` onto `main` as you did here. When you merge, the commits won't be rewritten, meaning their commit IDs will stay the same and the tags will stay pointing to the correct commits. Also, it's fairly common to use a branch named `develop` as a long lived shared branch (for example it is a common name in the Git Flow branching strategy). If it is a shared branch you should rarely, if ever rewrite it. This means you can rebase other branches onto `develop` but you should never rebase `develop` itself; `develop` should always be merged into another branch. That being said, if in your case `develop` is not actually a shared branch and you do intend to rebase it, then just wait to tag any commits until after they end up on `main` with their final commit IDs.